# Bug in ant 1.65 effects build which is running in ant 1.7+

Tags: ant, junit, jvm, ivy

**Updated question**

I have (since realizing that i have two versions of Ant in my classpath, as reported by my builder) come to the finding that my core issue is simply that an older version of Ant exists in my classpath.

To clarify, the following is reported at the beggining of my build process :

```
WARNING: multiple versions of ant detected in path for junit 

WARNING: multiple versions of ant detected in path for junit 
    [junit]          jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
    [junit]      and jar:file:/home/vagrant/Development/..../lib/ant-1.6.5.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
```

My new (simplified) question, then, is :

- What is the best way to force both ant and junit to utilize the correct ant version when running my junit tests, given that some other versions of ant might be transient dependencies in my classpath due to ivy ?

**Original question**

I notice that this version of ANT fixes a junitvm but :

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/trunk/WHATSNEW

- This bug involves the fact that the junitvmwatcher files created by ANT are not closed.
- However, In my recent ant build, the jvmwatcher bug persists.
- Any ideas why this bug might exist in an up to date ant installation ?

Answer (score 1):

The correct version of ANT should be the one running the build. So, what I often do is create a global exclusion for ANT in my **ivy.xml** file as follows:

```
    ..
    ..    
    <!-- Global exclusions -->
    <exclude org="org.apache.ant"/>
</dependencies>
```